# Weird laravel security behavior

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2

I am running an EC2 instance in amazon and a RDS instance, and everything works just fine. I upgraded RDS's instance type and also changed the master password as I regularly do once in a while.. 
But after the modification itself, I tried to login into my app (like, 30 seconds after I clicked on 'modify now'), before I changed the db credentials in my laravel .env file, and suddenly I saw an error page which **fully** exposed my db credentials for these 2-3 minutes before I updated them to the correct ones within the .env file. Needless to mention that there were at least a few dozens of people who probably tried to reach my app during this time as well.
So I was wondering whether it was a bad security practice done by myself or whether it's some laravel's flaw which wasn't yet handled?

The error message looked like this - (I replace the real credentials with realUserName / realPassword and realDbName, and the host name is censored as well)

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'realUserName'@'172.**.**.***' (using password: YES)
    1.  in Connector.php line 55
    2.  at PDO->__construct('mysql:host=testApp.*****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;dbname=realDbName', 'realUserName', 'realPassword', array('0', '2', '0', false, '0')) in Connector.php line 55
    3.  at Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=testApp.*****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;dbname=realDbName', array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'testApp.******.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', 'database' => 'realDbName', 'username' => 'realUserName', 'password' => 'realPassword', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql'), array('0', '2', '0', false, '0')) in MySqlConnector.php line 24
    4.  at MySqlConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'testApp.****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', 'database' => 'realDbName', 'username' => 'realUserName', 'password' => 'realPassword', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 61
    5.  at ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
    6.  at call_user_func(object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 924
```

Comment: It's clear, realUserName's password is wrong for DB

Comment: Did you even read the whole question?

Comment: Is it possible you changed APP_ENV or APP_DEBUG while modifying the .env?

Comment: There are only the db credentials in the .env file. I don't hold any other configuration there.

Comment: And 'debug' is set to false in config/app.php, @btl

Comment: it should be a question with bounty i guess :)

Comment: But what is the value for debug in your .env-file? In config/app.php there is only a fallback-value.

Comment: Is everything else hard coded into config files then?

Comment: @btl - Yes, as i answered previously - 'debug' is set to false in app.php

Comment: @Brotzka - there's no value for debug in .env file. I use the fallback value in app.php, which is false.

Comment: Definitely a strange case. You should consider immediately  running cache:clear and config:clear should you change these settings again.

Comment: @btl i think you are right, we should run `config:clear` changing config data

Comment: So.. how is it a solution for all these people who were exposed to my db credentials already?.. and nevertheless, there's no config.php in my bootstrap/cache folder, so I don't really know what config it'll clear..

Answer (score 2):

Many people (including me) already notified the Laravel developers that you never print credentials in an HTTP response, but the developers don't really seem to care. In fact, it's the only framework in the world that thinks it's OK to print critical information in a debug page.

If on the other hand, you do decide to use Laravel anyway, there's a package that counters this: https://github.com/GlaivePro/Hidevara It's really easy to setup, just make sure you don't forget the app->extend instruction. On a production server, you must not run "composer install" but instead "composer install --no-dev". This way filp/whoops will (should, hopefully) not be installed and cannot be triggered.

As a sidenote: the developers claim that nothing can go wrong when APP_DEBUG=false, but just as you pointed out, the whoops handler can be triggered when debug mode is disabled. Yet another case: https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.hacken.io/dangers-of-laravel-debug-mode-enabled%3fhs_amp=true

Comment: In the future, it would be advisable to sticking to answering the question instead of ranting. I took the ranting out, as there is an answer hidden in there.